# Script to add list of framework into xcode project?

Tags: ios, xcode, frameworks, linker

I need to run a script which should add the list of frameworks(AVFoundation, CoreData etc) into xCode project. is it possible? If yes how can I achieve this?

Any help and suggestion will be greatly appreciated....

Comment: how many projects do you have if the manual adding is not efficient enough?

Comment: I have sub 2 projects if I use it in my main project I need to add list of frame works to my main project. whenever I use those sub project I need to add around 30 frameworks I don't want to add it manually

Comment: You can refer to this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16422501/adding-libraries-frameworks-to-xcode-project-using-the-command-line/16436246#16436246